# Link markers together?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Can you somehow reference other markers inside a marker? Link markers together, even though they have different locations on a map.

Let's say I have two types of markers for each person:
1st marker is the location of where the person lives, 2nd marker is the location of where the person works.

Say there are many of these markers on my map. You hover over one. The one you've hovered over and the second marker that is linked to that marker(associated with the same person) is highlighted.

How would you do that, theoretically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an example, the idea is to keep an object (hash) or array of the various people, and when creating markers, assign who it belongs to (`marker.owner`). Later when it is selected, retrieve whose marker it is, and change the others from this information. The code below can be shortened, but the way it is left spread open you can see step-by-step what's going on.

http://jsfiddle.net/afTLh/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body, #map_canvas { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map;
      var mapOptions = { center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.0, -90.0), zoom: 5,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };

      var people = {};

      function initialize() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
        addPerson("Joe",40,-88,41,-86);
        addPerson("Tina",42,-92,43,-93);
        addPerson("Ken",39,-94,39.5,-96);
      }

      function addPerson(name, homelat, homelng, worklat, worklng) {
        people[name] = {};

        homemarker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(homelat, homelng),
          icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png'
        });

        workmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(worklat, worklng),
          icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png'
        });

        homemarker.owner = name;
        workmarker.owner = name;

        google.maps.event.addListener(homemarker, 'mouseover', function() {
          var name = this.owner;
          this.setIcon("http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png");
          people[name].work.setIcon("http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png");
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(homemarker, 'mouseout', function() {
          var name = this.owner;
          this.setIcon("http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png");
          people[name].work.setIcon("http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png");
        });


        google.maps.event.addListener(workmarker, 'mouseover', function() {
          var name = this.owner;
          this.setIcon("http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png");
          people[name].home.setIcon("http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png");
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(workmarker, 'mouseout', function() {
          var name = this.owner;
          this.setIcon("http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png");
          people[name].home.setIcon("http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png");
        });

        people[name].home = homemarker;
        people[name].work = workmarker;
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hmm. That is really interesting. I assume if you had all the data in a database, simply pulling who is the owner of what and placing into an array for each marker would work too.

Comment: Yeah, as long as names are not repeated it should work. Using my example I would call the `addPerson` function for each database row. Speaking of databases `name` should really be a unique id

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach which uses the built in `bindTo` method of all MVCObjects. This does not require the hash to keep track of which markers belong to each other.

In the mouseover events for the marker pairs, you just set some property to true, and set it to false on `mouseout`. Then bind the markers together by this property and use the change event for this property to set the icons.

http://jsfiddle.net/afTLh/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body, #map_canvas { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map;
      var mapOptions = { center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.0, -90.0), zoom: 5,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };

      function initialize() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
        addPerson("Joe",40,-88,41,-86);
        addPerson("Tina",42,-92,43,-93);
        addPerson("Ken",39,-94,39.5,-96);
      }

      function addPerson(name, homelat, homelng, worklat, worklng) {

        homemarker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(homelat, homelng),
          icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png'
        });

        workmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(worklat, worklng),
          icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png'
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(homemarker, 'mouseover', function() {
            this.set('current', true);
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(homemarker, 'mouseout', function() {
            this.set('current', false);
        });


        google.maps.event.addListener(workmarker, 'mouseover', function() {
            this.set('current', true);
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(workmarker, 'mouseout', function() {
            this.set('current', false);
        });

        //Use the 'current_changed' event to set the correct markers
        google.maps.event.addListener(workmarker, 'current_changed', function() {
            if(this.get('current')){
                this.setIcon("http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png");
            }else{
                this.setIcon("http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png");
            }
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(homemarker, 'current_changed', function() {
            if(this.get('current')){
                this.setIcon("http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png");
            }else{
                this.setIcon("http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png");
            }
        });

        //Bind the markers together by the 'current' property
        homemarker.bindTo('current', workmarker);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```